# Text is greyed out when JButton is disabled

Tags: java, html, swing, jbutton

I'm making Minesweeper for a school project. When a field/button is clicked, it gets disabled, and it shows its neighbors with a different color depending on the number of neighbors it has. I'm working on this in Eclipse. It works all perfectly and I'm almost ready to submit it. The only problem is that the colors work when run in Eclipse and JCreator, but when I run it with a `.bat`/command (`java Minesweeper`), the numbers show up greyed out instead of colored.

I change the colors with html tags when I call `setText()`. Ex: `setText("<html><font color=red>3</font></html>")` etc

Why is this happening? Colors work fine in Eclipse/JCreator, but not when I run the game through `cmd` or a batch script

Try this: It doesn't work for me...

Compile and run this in Eclipse/JCreator. Then try running it using `java Test`

The text will be red when run in Eclipse/JCreator, and grey when run in a script

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Test");
        JButton testButton = new JButton("Click this");

        MouseAdapter buttonListener = new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                int modifier = e.getModifiers();
                JButton clicked = (JButton)e.getSource();
                clicked.setForeground(Color.RED);
                clicked.setText("<html><font color=red>" + clicked.getText() + "</font></html>");
                clicked.setEnabled(false);
            }
        };

        mainFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(640,480));
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(testButton);
        testButton.addMouseListener(buttonListener);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Posting a short, self-contained, runnable code example would be helpful...something a person could compile and run.

Comment: There. Added some code that resembles my minesweeper code, and it replicates my problem too

Comment: I see the same behavior from Eclipse (Helios) and from command line `java Test` (java_1.6.0). Perhaps you've got a different default jvm's defined for Eclipse and command line.

Comment: Yeah but JCreator isn't as complicated as Eclipse. It's pretty much just a shell that executes a command when you click run or build

Comment: Now that I think about it... I do remember setting Eclipse AND JCreator to compile with JDK 6 u29 and run with JRE6 'cause my school uses Java 5 and I set mine to Java 6 to ensure compatibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the command `java` on my system points to JRE 1.7.0_1 instead of JRE 1.6.0_29 (even though I never added JRE 7's directory to the `PATH` variable...). And for some reason, this code behaves differently on the two JREs. On JRE 7, the text gets greyed out. On JRE 6, it behaves the way I want it to, and the text doesn't get greyed out.

Comment: Is it possible they might have fixed this [10 y.o (closed) bug](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4783068) in Swing HTML rendering but forgot to mark it as fixed?!?

Comment: BTW - this seems to answer the stated question.  If you agree, please mark it as correct when you get a moment.  As to **why** the rendering is different, that would be a worthy topic for another question.

Comment: What? That was actually a glitch? Wow

Answer (score 3):

you have to test for `JButton#isEnabled()`, for example

```
JButton.setText("<html><font color="
  + (bClose.isEnabled() ? "black" : "red") + ">"
  + bClose.getText() + "</font></html>");
```

and very nice is `JButton#setDisabledIcon(Icon)` too